# A word meaning "looking like the object that it describes"

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word that means "the word looks like the object it describes"?

For example: "bed" looks a bit like a bed, with the b and the d acting as head and foot boards, with the e as the mattress. "Shark" Looks a bit like a shark, with the capital *S* looking like the tail fin and the *k* looking like the mouth.

Comment: Well, what's the visual equivalent of 'onomatopoeia'?

Answer (score 8):

It is a type of *iconicity*.

[The Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iconicity) for iconicity currently begins:

> In functional-cognitive linguistics, as well as in semiotics, iconicity is the conceived similarity or analogy between the form of a sign (linguistic or otherwise) and its meaning, as opposed to arbitrariness.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is a particular type of [autological](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autological) word, but I haven't come across a discussion of this type before, so I don't know a word for it.

Comment: Likely considered a "self-autologlyph." While autologlyphs normally are in regards to art made to reflect the words, the fact these words inherently reflect their meaning is the reason why I would think they qualify.